# Python Dictionary - Combine Dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

Given a list of Dictionaries, return a new Dictionary of all of their keys combined.

This is what I have done so far:

```
def combine_dictionaries(dictionary_list):
    # your code goes here
    my_dictionary = {}

    for key in dictionary_list:

        my_dictionary.update(key, dictionary_list[key])

    return my_dictionary
```

This is the error it produces:
`list indices must be integers or slices, not dict`

Can someone let me know, how to get a integer when I have been provided a list of dictionaries?

The expected result should look something like this:

{'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'c': 4, 4: 4, 3: 3}

Comment: Can you please post the content of `dictionary_list`?

Comment: Hi Rafa - I just posted it.

Comment: Sorry Anitha, i didn't get it yet, please post an example of the "dictionary list" and what you expected as output...
When you say "dictionary list" i expect soething like this: `[{}, {}, {}, {}]`, but in your code you're looping using only "key" on `dictionary_list`

Comment: Hi Rafa - I got it to work.  No worries. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your function is almost there.
I believe that you should only pass `key` in your dictionnary update because the [update built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) accepts either another dictionary object or an iterable of key/value pairs.

```
def combine_dictionaries(dictionary_list):
    my_dictionary = {}
    for key in dictionary_list:
        my_dictionary.update(key)
    return my_dictionary
```